# Excel Number Scaling

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am working on a nutrition worksheet and I want to assign numeric values to nutrition measurements. For example, If I have the following for Vitamin C:

```
Guava 300mg
Papaya 250mg
Orange 180mg
Grapefruit 150mg
```

And I want to assign my own relative numeric values

```
Guava 20
Papaya ?
Orange ?
Grapefruit 5
```

How do I have Excel (or another tool) assign the relative values to Papaya and Orange based on the relative values I set myself.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the name, value, and units stored in a single cell? Are you looking for the formula to do proportions such that when 300 -> 20 the rest then 150 would change to 10?

Answer (score 1):

With data like:

[image]

In **C1** enter:

```
=0.1*B1-10
```

and copy down:

[image]

This is scaling by simple linear fit, using two points to calculate the **slope** and **intercept.**

**EDIT#1:**

To your second example, we put the formula for slope in **E4** and the formula for intercept in **E5** and the linear formulas in **C2** thru **C10** as follows:

[image]

Which results in:

[image]

For some interesting background, see:  [Walkenbach's material](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/)